# Timezone funciona localmente, pero no en pythonanywhere (DJango)

Tags: django, django-views

Tengo un **queryset** que lista todas las ventas de hoy:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class VentaToday(ListView):
    queryset = Venta.objects.filter(fecha=timezone.now()).order_by('-id')
    template_name = 'venta/venta_today.html'
```

En local, esto funciona correctamente pero en producción (Pythonanywhere) las ventas del día anterior siguen apareciendo. Para solucionarlo, tengo que ir al panel pythonanywhere y hacer clic en el botón ** recargar ** para resolver el problema o sea actualizar la página y ahí recién se desaparecen las ventas del día anterior.

He intentando cambiando la hora del servidor:

[image: Hora del servidor]

Y esta es la configuración de mi settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-pe'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Lima'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

¿Es un problema de caché en el servidor? o algo estoy haciendo mal? ya que en local no me pasa ese problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado:
Primero tuve que descargar **pytz** ya que el servidor al hacer un mantenimiento cambia la zona horaria.

```
pip install pytz
```

Luego pasando las 12 igual no actualizaba la lista... entonces tuve que remplazar mi queryset y retornando la lista con el filtro de pytz:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

class VentaToday(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Venta.objects.filter(fecha=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/Lima'))).order_by('-id')
    template_name = 'venta/venta_today.html'
```

Ahora pasando las 12AM reinicia nuevamente las ventas ! espero le ayude a alguien si le llega a pasar algo parecido.